# Is this if condition works in php

Tags: php

for a php web service i came across a situation for calculating percentage for a question having min 2 and max 5 multiple choice so i am trying like this
 I am using below condition

```
 $x=0;
 $y=5;

if($x < $row[0] < $y)
```

row[0] is for getting value from query
I tried but its not working properly is there any other method to calculate. I also tried like

```
   select (count(showdown_choice_id)*100/(select count(showdown_id) from showdown_response where  showdown_id='$showid')) from showdown_response where showdown_choice_id='$row[0]' and showdown_id=".$showid
```

but in while loop(containing values 1 to 5) same percentage is repeated for every choice.

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$x=0;
$y=5;

if($row[0] > $x && $row[0] < $y)
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
if($x < $row[0] < $y)
```

should be

```
if($x < $row[0] && $row[0] < $y)
```